# MongoDB Bulk import using mongoimport from Windows folder

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I have a lot of json files in archive and i need to import them into mongo per one operation (i think that it might be in cycle). Have you any ideas about this?

Comment: In which operating system you  want to import ?

Comment: I want to import in Win7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are in a Linux/Unix shell you can try

```
for filename in *; do mongoimport -d mydb -c $filename;  done
```

If you are on Windows:

```
FOR %i IN (C:\mongodbData\*.json) DO mongoimport --db dbName --collection colection --type json --file %i
```

Comment: Well, how it works?:) I'm copy this into the shell, edit db and col. Where i need to point a folder with jsons? @Sumeet

Comment: i have updated the answer. You can write windows path in IN parameter .@user3306125

Comment: Needs a semicolon after $filename before done, at least on OSX.

Comment: But this is importing everything in single collection i.e 'collection', what if there are the different collections with different names.? I would like to create collections with json file names without extension

Comment: error parsing command line options: expected argument for flag `/file'

Comment: this script works however it connected to mongodb client so in case of importing thousands of files it takes quite a lot of time. is there anyway to speed up the script?

Answer (score 4):

mongorestore is import all exported mongodb files

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin
mongorestore.exe -d <db name> C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\myProject\
```

But if you really want to import all only **meta** json files without .bson

```
cd C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\myProject\
FOR %i IN (*.json) DO "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongoimport.exe" --db <db name> --collection %~ni --type json --file %i
```

This is sample work on windows 10

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `mongorestore` for recovery from dump, created by the `mongodump`

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/program/mongorestore/

for example

`mongorestore --drop --oplogReplay  mongodb/`

Comment: Isn't mongorestore for BSON dump files rather than JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
FOR %i IN (<data folder>\*.json) DO mongoimport -d <database> -c <collection> --file %i
```